# Cannot call issue with jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a hard time with the script. This is what it should do:

---

When the **Geocode and submit** button is pressed it will do the following (this works already):

1. Check if result is already geocoded from autosuggest click
2. If not, geocode
3. Submit the form if successful

When the **Geocode** button is pressed I want it to do the following (this doesn't work):

1. Check if result is already geocoded from autosuggest click
2. If not, geocode

---

So my question is, how can I make it so I can use the same code for both scripts without having to duplicate it twice. My idea was to do the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/XyCF9/1/

```
$(function () {
    var lastQuery  = null,
        lastResult = null, // new!
        autocomplete,
        processLocation = function (input, lat, long, callback) { // accept a callback argument
            var query = $.trim(input.val()),
                geocoder;

            // if query is empty or the same as last time...
            if (!query || query === lastQuery) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(lastResult); // send the same result as before
                }
                return; // and stop here
            }

            lastQuery = query; // store for next time

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({address: query}, function (results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                    lng.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                    lastResult = true; // success!
                } else {
                    alert("Sorry - We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
                    lastResult = false; // failure!
                }
                if (callback) {
                    callback(lastResult); // send the result back
                }
            });
        },
        ctryiso = $("#ctry").val(),
        options = {
            types: ["geocode"]
        };

    if (ctryiso !== '') {
        options.componentRestrictions= { 'country': ctryiso };        
    }
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#loc")[0], options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', processLocation);

    $('#search').click(function (e) {
        var form = $(this).closest('form'),
            input = $("#loc"),
            lat = $("#lat"),
            lng = $("#lng");
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission

        processLocation(input, lat, lng, function (success) {
            if (success) { // if the geocoding succeeded, submit the form
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    });

    $('#geosearch').click(function (e) {
        var form = $(this).closest('form'),
            input = $("#geoloc"),
            lat = $("#geolat"),
            lng = $("#geolng");
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission

        processLocation(input, lat, lng);
    });
});
```

The error I'm getting at the moment is:

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined fiddle.jshell.net/:39
- Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'val' fiddle.jshell.net/:56

Can anyone shed some light on where I am going wrong with this please?

Comment: Hi, i tried your jsfiddle it works just fine ! your code populates the lat result successfully in both cases.

Comment: One possible issue of your error could be in the stmt $("#ctry").val(), some how your javascript is not able to find the element ctry in the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable name was `long` not `lng`

```
lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
long.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jfdbz/)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Only problem is when I try to use the form I still get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined fiddle.jshell.net/:39

Comment: It happens when I click on a suggestion from the autosuggest

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(lat).val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
$(lng).val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
```